# (Firebase Authentication Error) Uncaught Error: Component auth has not been registered yet

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am running into this problem using Firebase SDK

Here is the code snippet I am using for authentication

```
try {
    const email = "user@example.com"; // Replace with user's email
    const password = "password123"; // Replace with user's desired password

  const auth = getAuth()
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
 
    console.log("User registered:", userCredential.user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error signing up:", error.message);
  }
};
```

Tried npm install and uninstall. Nothing worked